# Google App Engine - Adding a record only if it doesn't exist yet

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In Google App Engine, consider the following datastore model:

```
class Update(db.Model):
    content = db.TextProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty()
    source = db.StringProperty()
```

To add a new record, I do something like:

```
db.put(Update(content=..., date=..., source=...))
```

How can I add a record to the datastore only if it doesn't exist yet? What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`db.Model.get_or_insert(key_name)`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_or_insert) lets you pass the key name of the object to get or insert (think of it like a primary key)

More information about [`key_name`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model)